# What is the default password of root for Centos?

Tags: centos, docker, root, centos-7

I building a docker image from a Dockerfile (downloaded from git hub). In the Dockerfile, there is such a line:

```
RUN useradd -m user
USER user
```

after this all the subsequent procedures happened under "user". When I was using the image, however, I realized that I was stuck inside "user" and couldn't switch to root anymore, because I don't know the password for root. The password was never specified inside the Dockerfile. The image is based on Centos7

How did this happen and is there a way to get the password?

I would really appreciate any hints!

Thank you so much

Comment: Did you google your question?...https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=What+is+the+default+password+of+root+for+Centos&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you're running an unprivileged docker container, you can't switch up to root from here without having set up a root password.

Fortunately, you don't have to setup a root password (and you should not). Instead, you can spawn a new process or container as root with the -u option:

```
docker run -u root imagename
```

or

```
docker exec -u root containername bash
```

Hint: also add `-it` flag if you need to interact with the process on the terminal.